# Timed Based Graph Plotting Python Django Using Firebase

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js, pyrebase

I am using Django to make a dashboard to show sensor data.
I am using chart.js for that
I am retrieving sensor data of two days or less only.
The problem is that how can I divide my graph for it.I think it might be possible using python time library or Django or something like that if so kindly suggest me some way to do it.
I think that if java script can help us that will be great too.
I just want data parsing based on time to plot and view it nicely.

Comment: you simply start on one side. E.g.. follow the linear Scale example for chart.js Once that works just feed data to it from your python code.

Comment: @user3732793 Linear scale example link? Actually I am getting date and time string every half an hour so I think chart.js will show them as label and I think they would look abnormal.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/linear-min-max.html